# Include exception message in JSON error response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

If email address already exists then throw an exception with a message("message:"User with "+tempEmailId+" already exists"). I don't get my exception message when I test in postman. Can you please help me ? Where is the issue? [image]

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationService service;
    
    @PostMapping("/registeruser")
    public  User registerUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        
        String tempEmailId = user.getEmailId();
        if(tempEmailId !=null && !"".equals(tempEmailId)) {
            User userObject = service.fetchUserByEmailId(tempEmailId);
            if(userObject!=null) {
                throw new Exception("User with "+tempEmailId+" is already exist");
            }
        }
        User userObject = null;
        userObject = service.saveUser(user);
        return userObject;

    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findByEmailId(String emailId);  // Here we declare 
}
```

Service:

```
@Service

public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired 
    private RegistrationRepository repo;
    
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return repo.save(user);
    }
    
    public User fetchUserByEmailId(String email) { 
        return repo.findByEmailId(email);   
    }
}
```

Comment: please post stacktrace from logs

Comment: The proper HTTP response code to give here would be 400 (bad request) as you're trying to create a user with an e-mail that already exists. So this code should give you the response you want for this case:  `throw new BadRequestException().setErrorMessage("User with " + tempEmailId + " already exists");`

Comment: It didnt work. In logs I can get this message (java.lang.Exception: User with eha.hoo@gmail.com is already exist). I want the same message in JSON in postman.

Comment: I suppose it will be better if you extract your registration business logic from controller to `RegistrationService`. And replace `!"".equals(tempEmailId)` to `!tempEmailId.isEmpty()` or you can add validation annotations from javax.validation.constraints package to class `User`. It won't solve your problem but makes your code more clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot version 2.3 or higher, the property `server.error.include-message` must be set to `always`:

Quoted from [Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content):

> **Changes to the Default Error Page’s Content**
>
> The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking information to a client. `server.error.include-message` and `server.error.include-binding-errors` can be used to control the inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported values are `always`, `on-param`, and `never`.

Comment: I added server.error.include-message=always in application.properties file. Now It is working

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your controller responses to `ResponseEntity`.

```
@PostMapping("/registeruser")
public  ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        String tempEmailId = user.getEmailId();
        if(tempEmailId != null && !tempEmailId.isEmpty()) {
            User userObject = service.fetchUserByEmailId(tempEmailId);
            if(userObject!=null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("User with "+tempEmailId+" is already exist", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.saveUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Or (preferable variant) your can create specific exception, for example `UserAlreadyExistException`, throw it in controller and intercept in class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`.
For example:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RegistrationControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler({UserAlreadyExistException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String userAlreadyExist(UserAlreadyExistException ex, WebRequest req) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Instead of String you can return any data structure serializable to JSON.